# How to make the Web Bluetooth Pair button work when run as chrome app

Tags: web-bluetooth

I have a simple set of HTML and JS which when I test it directly as a web page, loaded locally from the file system in Chrome, works fine. I can click a button causing a call to navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice. This correctly causes the usual window to appear and it lists the expected Bluetooth peripheral. I can then select it and successfully pair, with my code receiving the expected callback.

If I try to execute the same html/js as a Chrome app, with a manifest and invoked from chrome://extensions the requestDevice window appears and lists the expected peripheral with the Pair button disabled. If I select the peripheral, the Pair button becomes enabled but if I click it, the window disappears into the background, behind Chrome and nothing else happens that I can see. My code receives no callback. It looks like the call was competely ignored.

What do I need to do to make this work within a Chrome app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome Apps and Extensions should be able to use Web Bluetooth. This is a bug. I've filed [chromium issue 751819](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=751819).

As a work around, create the Chrome App window larger than the device chooser dialog that pops up.

Comment: Thanks Vincent, much appreciated :-)